# What does "his account of the proceedings" mean

Tags: word-meaning, legalese

> his account of the proceedings

Could you replace the words "account" and "proceeding" with simpler words?

Here is the full text:

> Only 123 of the defendants were present. The rest were either released, out on bail or on the run.
>
> "When the trial starts on Saturday and it is just a procedural hearing, and the judge doesn't listen to any lawyers or witnesses and doesn't even call the defendants, you are before a group of thugs and not the judiciary," Walid, a relative of one of the defendants, said by phone.
>
> It was not possible to confirm his account of the proceedings independently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context, "His account of the proceedings" means "What he said happened in court", as [StoneyB explains](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/19737/4468).

The phrase is also used more loosely to mean "What he said happened" in more general contexts. Although "proceedings" refers properly to a session of a court or some other formal meeting with a definite agenda, it can also be used to talk about any event, such as a sports match. In such cases, there might be a light-hearted suggestion that the event happened as if it had been formally planned.

Answer (score 4):

*Account* means a narrative, a telling of what happened—a *story*, but the word does not imply as *story* often does a fictional account. It is often used to contrast different versions of what happened:

> His account of the quarrel differed from Henry's: he claimed it started when Henry deliberately spilled his drink.

*Proceedings* means the actions of a body such as a court of law or a learned society during a formal session—an official 'sitting' or meeting.

*His account of the proceedings* thus means *His version of what happened in court while it was in session*.